# How to provide command line values to Java args within VS Code?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I try to run a Java program within VS Code and keep on getting the following error due to not able to pass in values for args in main() by clicking the "run java" icon.

```
'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\java.exe' '--enable-preview' '-XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages' '-cp' 'C:\Users\llee\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage\6a201af46b5315f239f3bba771ed2cc7\redhat.java\jdt_ws\Lecture 1_b97312ef\bin' 'Sort_Three' 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 
out of bounds for length 0
        at Sort_Three.main(Sort_Three.java:3)
```

I understand that variable args is null and there is no value passed to the program. So, what should I do to pass values for VS Code by clicking on the "run java" icon?

If I run the program outside VS Code on a command line, the program works fine.

```
PS C:\Users\Desktop\Exercises\Lecture 1> java Sort_Three 3 1 2
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [create a Run/Debug Configuration that includes an `args` array](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-debugging#_launch)

It'll create a `.vscode/launch.json` file with at least this content

```json
{
... 
"type": "java",
"mainClass": "Sort_Three",
"args": [3, 1, 2]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your example, by adding the list to args, I can run the program within the IDE now.  

'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\java.exe' '-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,suspend=y,address=localhost:63533' '--enable-preview' '-XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages' '-cp' 'C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage\6a201af46b5315f239f3bba771ed2cc7\redhat.java\jdt_ws\bin' 'Sort_Three' '3' '1' '2'       
1
2
3